# Perpetuity Question with first payment period between payment periods and start.

Tags: finance

An employer wants to pay 450 dollars every 6 months to a deserving employee forever. The company has $A to fund the award and can earn j2= 7%(interest compounded semi-annually). If the first award is to be paid out 3 months from now, what is A?

i = 0.07/2 = 0.035

-So I've tried A = 450/0.035 and I didn't get the right answer

-I've tried A = 450 + 450/0.035 and that's not correct

-I've even tried (1.035)^-1*450/0.035

-I've also tried mixing the formulas but I still don't get the correct result and there are no examples or similar methods I could find in my textbook. I'm not sure how to approach this question at all.

Comment: Your first answer would be correct if the first payment was 6 months from now instead of 3 months.

Comment: What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_3 \equiv \frac{450}{0.035}$$
Is the amount that you need in the account in three months time after earning 3 months interest and paying your first \$450

The six month growth factor is 1.035

so the three month growth factor is $\sqrt {1.035}$

So your initial amount $A$ is the solution to ...
$$ A\sqrt {1.035}   -450=a_3$$